# subscribe a custom event handler to the state of a redux store created by redux toolkit's configureStore

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React app in which the store is created like this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        // ... multiple reducers are defined here
    },
    middleware: [thunk]
});
```

I use `import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';` to feed react components with the redux state, but in one part of the code, I have a custom function (not part of any React Components), that I need to be triggered when a specific part of the state changes. How can I do this?

I was about to use `store.subscribe()` but it says `store.subscribe is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

The right answer for this is to use the new RTK "listener" middleware:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware

You can dispatch the `addListener` action creator to dynamically add a listener that watches for state changes using the `predicate` option:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#standard-usage-patterns
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#adding-listeners-inside-components

```
import { addListener } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = dispatch(addListener({
      predicate: (action, currentState, prevState) => {
        return currentState.some.field !== prevState.some.field;
      },
      effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
        // some logic here that will run when `state.some.field` changes
      }
    }))

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
}
```

As a side note: you don't need to list `middleware: [thunk]` , as the thunk middleware is already added to the store by default with `configureStore`.